# Image inside HTML anchor creates unwanted artefact

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a pretty basic header that I am working on right now and for some unknown reasons the anchors that has an image tag inside them creates some unwanted artefact like in the following print-screen:

[image]
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEHMp.png)

HTML

```
<div class="block-content">
    <form method="get" id="header-searchform" class="search-form search-button-hidden" action="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/" _lpchecked="1">
        <div>
            <input id="search" class="field" type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Indtast søgeord">
        </div>
    </form>
    <a id="stof2000-logo" href="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/">
        <img src="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/stof2000logo.png" alt="Stof 2000">
    </a>
    <a id="klarparatsy-logo" href="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/">
        <img src="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/klarparatsy-logo.png" alt="Stof 2000">
    </a>
    <img id="homemade-logo" src="http://klarparatsy.stof2000.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/homemade-logo.png" alt="Stof 2000">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#stof2000-logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 39px;
    left: 80px;
}
#klarparatsy-logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
    left: 143px;
}
```

The artefacts are created next to the images boundaries and I can't see the issue in the code so any guidance is more than welcomed. I know it's a small issue but it is very frustrating at the moment..

Comment: that's probably an underlinement from the `a href`, because links are always standard underlined. let me search for the right line of code to disable that..

Comment: try `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @myfunkyside is right. Also think about closing your image tags. ex. `<img src="image.jpg" />`

Comment: @myfunkyside Thats correct, you should put that as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an underlinement from the anchor (`a href`), because links are always standard underlined.

`text-decoration:none;` should fix it.

---

Put it on the two anchors in the CSS, like so:

```
#stof2000-logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 39px;
    left: 80px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: It fix it. Damn, it was so easy but it didn't goes through my head. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'd be much obliged if you could give me one of those fancy checkmarks:)

Answer (score 2):

Anchors are usually underlined. Thats why you get this "artefact". 
You can remove that line from all anchors on your page with

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Or even just for those containing the images, like this:

```
#stof2000-logo, 
#klarparatsy-logo { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: I am sorry but @myfunkyside was faster

Answer (score 1):

At images and links it's always better so set the images to block-elements:

```
.block-content img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.block-content a,
.block-content a:link,
.block-content a:visited {
    padding: 0;
}
```

In styles directly at the img-elements use width and padding to position them.